# email compose task is not working windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

how to send email in windows phone 8.1 app using a button ?

```
EmailRecipient sendTo = new EmailRecipient()
{
    Address = "abc@outlook.com"
};

//generate mail object
EmailMessage mail = new EmailMessage();
mail.Subject = "Feedback";


//add recipients to the mail object
mail.To.Add(sendTo);
//mail.Bcc.Add(sendTo);
//mail.CC.Add(sendTo);

//open the share contract with Mail only:
await EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync(mail);
```

I'm getting error saying:

> "Error 1 The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method.
>   Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing
>   its return type to 'Task'."

Comment: I think error message is pretty clear...

Comment: Make your method as async if you're using the await.

Answer (score 1):

You need to mark your event handler with the `async` keyword to be able to `await` inside it:

```
public async void MyButtonHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   EmailRecipient sendTo = new EmailRecipient()
   {
       Address = "abc@outlook.com"
   };

   //generate mail object
   EmailMessage mail = new EmailMessage();
   mail.Subject = "Feedback";

   //add recipients to the mail object
   mail.To.Add(sendTo);
   //mail.Bcc.Add(sendTo);
   //mail.CC.Add(sendTo);

   //open the share contract with Mail only:
   await EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync(mail);
}
```